# Periodically switching sink file name

Tags: python, qt, gstreamer

I have to save video streams to HDD. I was trying to do that as frames, but this is quite expensive for the hardware (HDD). Saving encoded video was more gentle using the pipeline (test):

videotestsrc is-live=true | videorate | video/x-raw-rgb,framerate=24/1 | ffmpegcolorspace | x264enc | matroskamux | filesink location=file_X.avi

However I would like to "rotate" destination file every now and then, without dropping frames. Is this possible in GStreamer (some element can do this or can help), or there is some technique to do that? (C++ or Python)